# Ng grid data with more than 10,000 records unable to print in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, ng-grid

I am using Ng grid 2.x version and i have huge sets of records which can run upto to 10000 records each record may contain a maximum of 7 columns and i am trying to implement a simple one button print option but it doesnt work in firefox it is crashing what i am doing is listed below

1. I am creating a table of all the 10k records
2. i am sending that to print

this is working in all the browsers except firefox

Note:- i am aware of the fact that firefox has a bug displaying any rows above 20,000 but i am just trying for 10,000 records.

I need to get this to work very badly can one of you please provide me with some solution:(

Answer (score 0):

10k Rows on a table?! Can't you paginate this? That's crazy.

Ok let's assume you *have* to put all 10k records at once in a table and you *have* to do this in the browser.

You should write your own solution using ng-repeat and bind once syntax.

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="record in records">
   {{::record}}
</div>
```

`::` is the bind once syntax. If you don't use this, your app would be watching all 10k records to see if any value has changed. This can use a lot of resources and crash a browser. If you have 7 columns per row, that could be 70,000 watched values!